# Save picture box image

Tags: c#, save, picturebox

I've written this code but it throws a generic error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I believe it's because I'm trying to save the `pictureBox.Image` without ever actually setting the image. How do I save the image that is in the `pictureBox`?

```
            // Left Arm Rear
            bmp = new Bitmap(4, 12);
            g3 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g3.DrawImageUnscaled(pictureBoxSkin.Image, -52, -20, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            g2 = pictureBoxLabel.CreateGraphics();
            bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
            g2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 28, 20, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            // Back
            bmp = new Bitmap(8, 12);
            g3 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g3.DrawImageUnscaled(pictureBoxSkin.Image, -32, -20, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            g2 = pictureBoxLabel.CreateGraphics();
            bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);
            g2.DrawImageUnscaled(bmp, 32, 20, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);

            pictureBoxLabel.Image.Save(openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) + "_label.Png");
```

Comment: You really try to step in this code with a debugger and find the line that throws the exception. Also you use two different controls `pictureBoxSkin.Image` and `pictureBoxLabel.Image`, is that intentional?

Comment: The two images are intentional. The line that throws the error is the save line on the bottom. Like I said, I think it is because I'm trying to save the image in the pictureBoxLabel without having assigned an image to it. It has an image but it was added using creategraphics. What's the correct line to save the graphic that was created?

Comment: There's too much in one line if you already know that it throws an error. Assemble the filename in the line above. Call `Save` only with a string as parameter to get closer to the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, can you check the response below?

Answer (score 0):

If `NullReferanceException` throwns on last line there are a few posibilities;

```
pictureBoxLabel.Image.Save(openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName) + "_label.Png");
```

- `pictureBoxLabel` could be `null`.
- `openFileDialog1` could be `null`.

Check these objects in your debugging time.

But if `pictureBoxLabel` is null, there could thrown `NullReferanceException` also on this line;

```
g2 = pictureBoxLabel.CreateGraphics();
```

So, my money is for `openFileDialog1` is `null`.

Comment: openFileDialog is good. If I swap the pictureBox object for the bitmap one it saves the file to the correct location so the filepath is good. I think the problem is that the pictureBoxLabel.Image is null. When the code is run it disects the pictureBoxSkin.Image, rearranges it and draws it to the pictureBoxLabel so on the WinForm I see an image in the pictureBoxLabel. But I don't actually set the pictureBoxLabel.Image property. How do I save the image that I see in the box on the WinForm?

Comment: @luigivampa Check Image property from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.image(v=vs.80).aspx